# Why using <a href="file.mkv"> here </a> (local file) chrome doesnt play the audio?

Tags: html

I want play a local videos using chrome

Using `<a href="file.mkv">Press here for the video</a>` (file in same folder) chrome play the video unless audio. Why?

Comment: For playing audio, you can use the HTML5 audio tag.

Comment: Would you like to play just the audio, just the video or both?

Comment: i would play video and audio

Answer (score 1):

Playing audio using below HTML5 code

```
<audio
        controls
        src="file.mp3">
            Your browser does not support the
            <code>audio</code> element.
    </audio>
```